# How to optimize a 2 table query where data can be only discriminated based on both tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have the following 2 tables and data distribution:

```
drop table if exists line;
drop table if exists header;

create table header (header_id serial primary key, type character);
create table line (line_id serial primary key, header_id serial not null, type character, constraint line_header foreign key (header_id) references header (header_id)) ;
create index inv_type_idx on header (type);
create index line_type_idx on line (type);

insert into header (type) select case when floor(random()*2+1) = 1 then  'A' else 'B' end from generate_series(1,100000);
insert into line (header_id, type) select header_id,  case when floor(random()*10000+1) = 1 then (case when type ='A' then 'B' else 'A' end) else type end from header, generate_series(1,5);
```

- `header` table has 100K rows: 50% of `type` A and 50% of B
- `line` table has 500K rows:

  - each `header` has 5 `line`s
  - overall there are 50% of lines of `type` A and 50% of B
  - `type` of a `line` is the same as its `header` in 99.99% of the cases, in only 0.01% they are different

Data distribution:

```
# select h.type header_type, l.type line_type, count(*) from line l inner join header h on l.header_id = h.header_id group by 1,2 order by 1,2;
 header_type | line_type | count  
-------------+-----------+--------
 A           | A         | 250865
 A           | B         |     25
 B           | A         |     29
 B           | B         | 249081
(4 rows)
```

I need to get all the `line`s with `type` B whose `header` is A. Even the total amount is very limited (25 out of 500000 rows) the plan I obtain (PostgreSQL 10) is the following, which performs a **sequential scan** in both  both tables:

```
explain
select * from line l
   inner join header h on l.header_id = h.header_id
where h.type ='A' and l.type='B';

                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=2323.29..14632.89 rows=125545 width=19)
   Hash Cond: (l.header_id = h.header_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on line l  (cost=0.00..11656.00 rows=248983 width=13)
         Filter: (type = 'B'::bpchar)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1693.00..1693.00 rows=50423 width=6)
         ->  Seq Scan on header h  (cost=0.00..1693.00 rows=50423 width=6)
               Filter: (type = 'A'::bpchar)
(7 rows)
```

Is there any way to optimize this kind of queries where data discrimination is very high but only when combining information from more than one table?

Of course, as workaround I could denormalize information storing in `line`s information from `header` which would make this query much more performant. But if possible, I'd prefer not to have to do so because I'd need to maintain this duplicated information.

```
alter table line add column compound_type char(2);
create index compound_idx on line (compound_type);

update line l
   set compound_type = h.type || l.type
  from header h
 where h.header_id = l.header_id;

# explain select * from line where compound_type = 'BA';
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using compound_idx on line  (cost=0.42..155.58 rows=50 width=13)
   Index Cond: (compound_type = 'BA'::bpchar)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I don't know that there is a way of avoiding the full scan on at least one table (and looking up the corresponding rows in the other).  You don't know *which* of the 50% have the wrong types.  Instead, design your data structure to store the type in only the header, and look it up when you need it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't see how can I structure it to make performant without data duplicities

Comment: With **triggers** I find your `compound_type` adequate. As there is some redundancy a boolean column `types_differing = h.type != l.type` might be better style, though you need to inspect two columns then. **Alternatively** if there were a time stamp, you could also have a table of lines with differing lines found upto some point of time, and update that table on need. Needs indices on the timestamps.

Comment: Your indexes won't help much, as their selectivity is at around 50%, so the planner will most probably never use them.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use materialized view with proper index. It can update in "background". Otherwise it's similar to your composed index in line.

2) You can reverse the search to header-to-line if you create index on (line.header_id, line.type) and force subquery like this:

```
select header_id 
from header h 
where type='A' and 
    exists(select * from line l where l.header_id=h.header_id and l.type='B')
```

After you get all headers make another select of lines with corresponding header_id.

It might be good idea to include type into some headers index so that 2 indexes are everything needed for look-up.

Still it will read ~50K lines in headers index and look up each of them in 2nd index. In general it's not effective, but if indexes fully fit into memory, it might be not so bad.

Comment: 1. A materialized view is a way of data denormalization or duplicities which is what I wanted to avoid, in this case I don't see it better than my `compound_type` updated via triggers.     2. In the plan for that query I still see 2 seq scans (one in each table)